# Spring Data Graph as a REST client - what are the adventages?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I apologize if this is a trivial  question, but I would like to know what are the advantages / disadvantages of Spring Data Graph as a REST client upon Embedded database?
I'm using neo4j.

Thanks
Carmel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your use-case. There are pros and cons.

Pros REST:

-> Different services can access the neo4j DB (sample: i have one service that is responsible for Nodes of kind A,B and C. The second service is responsible for nodes D and H and can connect D-nodes to A-nodes). In that way i have clean domain structures. Every service is only responsible for its own domain nodes. I can update each service and don't have to shutdown my whole application.

-> I can access the neo4j DB from different languages (PHP)

Cons: - Performance is not that good as an EmbeddedGraphDatabase (since the neo4j server and the services are on the same machine the latency is not that big). - No transactions

One other pro for the server is the web-admin / visualization.

You have some more options. You can have an embedded graphdb for high performance and have only some services run embedded, and use a custom, domain centric remote (REST or otherwise) API to expose the graph database for other services.

The same can be achieved by using the Neo4j Server and add some of the more performance critical services as Server-Plugins or Extensions which are also able to expose a custom remote API that suits your use-cases probably better.

I would start using the embedded graph db for developing your services, if you want to expose certain endpoints to other services later, it is quite easy to switch to the Neo4j server.

In the REST-API there is one transaction per request, for larger operations there is a batch operation in the API.